# Records are being removed whilst parsing through XML

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, elementtree

I'm parsing my XML into a Pandas DF, but I'm losing records in the while doing it. Not all records have all attributes. When this is the case, I notice that that the record (row in DF) is removed from the DF, instead of it being replaced with "None".

Is there a way to mitigate this? I can't seem to find the solution.

I pasted my code below as a reference:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

tree = et.parse('20191125_DMG_PI.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

df_cols = ["status",
           "priref",
           "full_name",
           "achternaam",
           "geboorteplaats",
           "sterfplaats",
           "detail",
           "adres",
           "zip",
           "note",
           "gender"]
rows = []

for record in root:
    for child in record:
        s_priref = ""
        s_priref = child.get('priref')
    for child in record:
        s_name_note = ""
        s_name_note = child.get('name.note')
    for child in record:
        s_surname = ""
        s_surname = child.find('surname')

        for field in child.findall('Address'):
            s_adress = ""
            s_address = field.find('address').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('Address'):
            s_zip = ""
            s_zip = field.find('address.postal_code').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('name'):
            s_full_name = ""
            s_full_name = field.find('value').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('name.status'):
            s_status = ""
            s_status = field.find('value').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('level_of_detail'):
            s_detail = ""
            s_detail = field.tag + ": " + field.find('value').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('gender'):
            s_gender = ""
            s_gender = field.find('value').text

        for field in child.findall('birth.place'):
            s_gbp = ""
            s_gbp = field.find('value').text if field is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('death.place'):
            s_pvo = ""
            if len(field.findall('death.place')) == 0:
                s_pvo = "NaN"
            else:
                s_pvo = field.find('value').text if field is not None else None

            rows.append({"status": s_status,
                         "priref": s_priref,
                         "full_name": s_full_name,
                         "achternaam": s_surname,
                         "geboorteplaats": s_gbp,
                         "sterfplaats": s_pvo,
                         "detail": s_detail,
                         "adres": s_address,
                         "zip": s_zip,
                         "note": s_name_note,
                         "gender": s_gender
                         })

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
print(out_df)
```

First three records as examples below:

```
<recordList><record priref="530000001" creation="2014-06-23T11:36:18" modification="2019-09-13T09:07:12">
  <name>
    <value lang="">C.I.A.P.</value>
  </name>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">ACQUISITIONSOURCE</value>
    <value lang="0">acquisition source</value>
    <value lang="1">verwervingsbron</value>
    <value lang="2">source d'acquisition</value>
    <value lang="3">Erwerbungsquelle</value>
    <value lang="5">fonte di acquisizione</value>
    <value lang="6">πηγή απόκτησης</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">INST</value>
    <value lang="0">institution</value>
    <value lang="1">instelling</value>
    <value lang="2">institution</value>
    <value lang="3">Institution</value>
    <value lang="4">المؤسسة</value>
    <value lang="5">istituto</value>
    <value lang="6">οργανισμός</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.status>
    <value lang="neutral">1</value>
    <value lang="0">approved preferred term</value>
    <value lang="1">descriptor</value>
    <value lang="2">descripteur</value>
    <value lang="3">Deskriptor</value>
    <value lang="5">termine preferenziale approvato</value>
  </name.status>
  <Address>
    <address>Lombaardstraat 23</address>
    <address.country>
      <value lang="">België</value>
    </address.country>
    <address.place>
      <value lang="">Hasselt</value>
    </address.place>
    <address.postal_code>3500</address.postal_code>
    <address.type />
  </Address>
  <level_of_detail>
    <value lang="neutral">PARTIAL</value>
    <value lang="0">partial</value>
    <value lang="1">partieel</value>
    <value lang="2">partiel</value>
    <value lang="3">partiell</value>
    <value lang="5">parziale</value>
  </level_of_detail>
  <birth.place>
    <value lang="">Hasselt</value>
  </birth.place>
  <id_number>53</id_number>
  <supplier.letter.processing>
    <value lang="neutral">PRINT</value>
    <value lang="0">Print to documents</value>
    <value lang="1">Afdrukken naar documenten</value>
    <value lang="2">Imprimer en documents</value>
    <value lang="3">Ausdruck in Dokumenten</value>
    <value lang="5">Stampa nei documenti</value>
  </supplier.letter.processing>
  <name.note>Centrum voor Informatie en Aktueel Prentenkabinet</name.note>
  <Place_activity>
    <place_activity.institution />
    <place_activity.type />
    <place_activity>
      <value lang="">Hasselt</value>
    </place_activity>
    <place_activity.notes />
    <place_activity.date.end />
    <place_activity.date.start />
  </Place_activity>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-13</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>09:07:12</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>13:15:16</edit.time>
  </Edit>
</record><record priref="530000003" creation="2014-06-23T11:36:18" modification="2019-09-13T09:02:51">
  <name>
    <value lang="">Goossens, K.</value>
  </name>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">ACQUISITIONSOURCE</value>
    <value lang="0">acquisition source</value>
    <value lang="1">verwervingsbron</value>
    <value lang="2">source d'acquisition</value>
    <value lang="3">Erwerbungsquelle</value>
    <value lang="5">fonte di acquisizione</value>
    <value lang="6">πηγή απόκτησης</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">PERSON</value>
    <value lang="0">person</value>
    <value lang="1">persoon</value>
    <value lang="2">personne</value>
    <value lang="3">Person</value>
    <value lang="4">إسم شخص</value>
    <value lang="5">persona</value>
    <value lang="6">πρόσωπο</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.status>
    <value lang="neutral">1</value>
    <value lang="0">approved preferred term</value>
    <value lang="1">descriptor</value>
    <value lang="2">descripteur</value>
    <value lang="3">Deskriptor</value>
    <value lang="5">termine preferenziale approvato</value>
  </name.status>
  <surname>Goossens</surname>
  <Address>
    <address>Morckhovelei</address>
    <address.country>
      <value lang="">België</value>
    </address.country>
    <address.place>
      <value lang="">Borgerhout</value>
    </address.place>
    <address.postal_code />
    <address.type />
  </Address>
  <nationality>
    <value lang="">Belgisch</value>
  </nationality>
  <level_of_detail>
    <value lang="neutral">PARTIAL</value>
    <value lang="0">partial</value>
    <value lang="1">partieel</value>
    <value lang="2">partiel</value>
    <value lang="3">partiell</value>
    <value lang="5">parziale</value>
  </level_of_detail>
  <forename>K.</forename>
  <gender>
    <value lang="neutral">FEMALE</value>
    <value lang="0">female</value>
    <value lang="1">vrouw</value>
    <value lang="2">femme</value>
    <value lang="3">weiblich</value>
    <value lang="5">femmina</value>
    <value lang="6">θηλυκό</value>
  </gender>
  <id_number>53</id_number>
  <supplier.letter.processing>
    <value lang="neutral">PRINT</value>
    <value lang="0">Print to documents</value>
    <value lang="1">Afdrukken naar documenten</value>
    <value lang="2">Imprimer en documents</value>
    <value lang="3">Ausdruck in Dokumenten</value>
    <value lang="5">Stampa nei documenti</value>
  </supplier.letter.processing>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-13</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>09:02:51</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>13:21:05</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>13:20:03</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>13:19:45</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-09-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>13:19:16</edit.time>
  </Edit>
</record><record priref="530000004" creation="2014-06-23T11:36:18" modification="2019-07-19T09:55:26">
  <name>
    <value lang="">De Bruyne, Pieter</value>
  </name>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">MAKER</value>
    <value lang="0">creator</value>
    <value lang="1">vervaardiger</value>
    <value lang="2">créateur</value>
    <value lang="3">Hersteller</value>
    <value lang="4">الصانع</value>
    <value lang="5">creatore</value>
    <value lang="6">δημιουργός</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">ACQUISITIONSOURCE</value>
    <value lang="0">acquisition source</value>
    <value lang="1">verwervingsbron</value>
    <value lang="2">source d'acquisition</value>
    <value lang="3">Erwerbungsquelle</value>
    <value lang="5">fonte di acquisizione</value>
    <value lang="6">πηγή απόκτησης</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">PERSON</value>
    <value lang="0">person</value>
    <value lang="1">persoon</value>
    <value lang="2">personne</value>
    <value lang="3">Person</value>
    <value lang="4">إسم شخص</value>
    <value lang="5">persona</value>
    <value lang="6">πρόσωπο</value>
  </name.type>
  <name.type>
    <value lang="neutral">AUTHOR</value>
    <value lang="0">author</value>
    <value lang="1">auteur</value>
    <value lang="2">auteur</value>
    <value lang="3">Verfasser</value>
    <value lang="4">المؤلف</value>
    <value lang="5">autore</value>
    <value lang="6">συντάκτης</value>
  </name.type>
  <birth.date.start>1931</birth.date.start>
  <death.date.start>1987</death.date.start>
  <name.status>
    <value lang="neutral">1</value>
    <value lang="0">approved preferred term</value>
    <value lang="1">descriptor</value>
    <value lang="2">descripteur</value>
    <value lang="3">Deskriptor</value>
    <value lang="5">termine preferenziale approvato</value>
  </name.status>
  <surname>De Bruyne</surname>
  <Address>
    <address>Stationstraat 16</address>
    <address.country>
      <value lang="">België</value>
    </address.country>
    <address.place>
      <value lang="">Aalst</value>
    </address.place>
    <address.postal_code>9300</address.postal_code>
    <address.type>woning Pieter De Bruyne</address.type>
  </Address>
  <biography>Pieter De Bruyne is als pionier binnen het postmodern ontwerpen een internationaal geapprecieerde meubelontwerper. Hij wijdde zijn hele leven aan de vernieuwing van het meubilair. De Bruynes werk sluit aan bij de Memphis-stijl, hoewel hij nooit actief deel wilde uitmaken van dergelijke bewegingen. Elk meubel van zijn hand opent nieuwe perspectieven en is stimulans om andere denkrichtingen in te slaan. 

Bibliotheek Design museum Gent:     
(1) Pieter De Bruyne 1931- 1987. Pionier van het postmoderne.  / Christian Kieckens, Eva Storgaard
(2) 25 jaar Pieter De Bruyne. / Christian Norberg-Schulz</biography>
  <Source>
    <source>http://vocab.getty.edu/page/ulan/</source>
    <source.number>500009402</source.number>
  </Source>
  <Source>
    <source>https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/</source>
    <source.number>Q14101030</source.number>
  </Source>
  <death.date.end>1987</death.date.end>
  <death.place>
    <value lang="">Aalst</value>
  </death.place>
  <nationality>
    <value lang="">Belgisch</value>
  </nationality>
  <level_of_detail>
    <value lang="neutral">FULL</value>
    <value lang="0">full</value>
    <value lang="1">volledig</value>
    <value lang="2">complet</value>
    <value lang="3">vollständig</value>
    <value lang="5">completo</value>
  </level_of_detail>
  <forename>Pieter</forename>
  <birth.date.end>1931</birth.date.end>
  <birth.place>
    <value lang="">Aalst</value>
  </birth.place>
  <gender>
    <value lang="neutral">MALE</value>
    <value lang="0">male</value>
    <value lang="1">man</value>
    <value lang="2">homme</value>
    <value lang="3">männlich</value>
    <value lang="5">maschio</value>
    <value lang="6">αρσενικό</value>
  </gender>
  <occupation>
    <value lang="">ontwerper</value>
  </occupation>
  <Part_of>
    <part_of>
      <value lang="">Pieter De Bruyne N.V.</value>
    </part_of>
    <part_of.notes />
    <part_of.category />
    <part_of.date.end />
    <part_of.date.start />
  </Part_of>
  <Equivalent>
    <equivalent_name>
      <value lang="">Pieter De Bruyne N.V.</value>
    </equivalent_name>
    <equivalent_name.category />
  </Equivalent>
  <id_number>53</id_number>
  <supplier.letter.processing>
    <value lang="neutral">PRINT</value>
    <value lang="0">Print to documents</value>
    <value lang="1">Afdrukken naar documenten</value>
    <value lang="2">Imprimer en documents</value>
    <value lang="3">Ausdruck in Dokumenten</value>
    <value lang="5">Stampa nei documenti</value>
  </supplier.letter.processing>
  <school_style>
    <value lang="">post-modernisme</value>
  </school_style>
  <language>
    <value lang="">Nederlands</value>
  </language>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-07-19</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>09:55:26</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-07-19</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>09:55:24</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-07-17</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>11:24:24</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-06-18</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>11:54:47</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-06-12</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>11:44:02</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-05-28</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>08:20:09</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-05-27</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:44:41</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-05-13</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>14:24:58</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-05-13</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>14:23:25</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>people&gt;people</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-04-23</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>16:12:25</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>thesau&gt;thesau</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2019-04-18</edit.date>
    <edit.name>ovandhuynslager</edit.name>
    <edit.time>15:19:53</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>COLLECT&gt;intern</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2016-09-26</edit.date>
    <edit.name>rgoris</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:58:19</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>COLLECT&gt;intern</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2016-09-26</edit.date>
    <edit.name>rgoris</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:57:40</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>COLLECT&gt;intern</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2016-09-26</edit.date>
    <edit.name>rgoris</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:50:49</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>COLLECT&gt;intern</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2016-09-26</edit.date>
    <edit.name>rgoris</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:21:40</edit.time>
  </Edit>
  <Edit>
    <edit.notes />
    <edit.source>COLLECT&gt;intern</edit.source>
    <edit.date>2016-09-26</edit.date>
    <edit.name>rgoris</edit.name>
    <edit.time>10:20:30</edit.time>
  </Edit>
```

Comment: You need to include a meaningful sample of the XML structure (e.g. one complete record, one incomplete one).

Comment: @tomalak I've added the first three records. There aren't really 'incomplete ones' I guess none of the records have all attributes in them.

Comment: Seeing the XML is a big help nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the part of the code that deals with the XML by switching to XPath as the means of locating any given node. Consider this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def node_text(node, default=''):
    return node.text if node is not None and node.text is not None else default

tree = et.parse('20191125_DMG_PI.xml')

rows = []
for record in tree.iterfind('./record'):
    rows.append({
        'status':         node_text(record.find('./name.status/value')),
        'priref':         record.get('priref'),
        'full_name':      node_text(record.find('./name/value')),
        'achternaam':     node_text(record.find('./surname')),
        'geboorteplaats': node_text(record.find('./birth.place/value')),
        'sterfplaats':    node_text(record.find('./death.place/value')),
        'detail':         node_text(record.find('./level_of_detail/value[@lang="neutral"]')),
        'adres':          node_text(record.find('./Address/address')),
        'zip':            node_text(record.find('./Address/address.postal_code')),
        'note':           node_text(record.find('./name.note')),
        'gender':         node_text(record.find('./gender/value'))
    })

print(rows)
```

The `node_text()` helper function at the top deals with the "node not found" situation. You can use `None` as the default if you prefer that over the empty string, or pass individual defaults per value.

XPaths in ElementTree must begin with `./` and are limited to a sub-set of what XPath 1.0 can do, but that's more than enough for your use-case.

Getting `rows` into a dataframe afterwards should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! I'll put this to the test.

Comment: I keep getting this traceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/oliviervandhuynslager/.conda/envs/DesignMuseumGent/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Users/oliviervandhuynslager/.conda/envs/DesignMuseumGent/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 417131, column 2

Comment: The file also opens/close with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adlibXML> ... </adlibXML> -last line is 417131

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the code in my answer. You will have to figure it out  yourself.

Comment: I'm breaking my head on this. There are no mismatched tags anywhere. There's something I'm missing here but still, after reading the documentation I can't figure out what it is I'm looking for. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: There definitely is a mismatched tag when the XML parser says so. Try to open the XML file with a web browser, the display where the error is might be more informative there.

Comment: I know there must be something wrong. But the begin and end tags seem fine to me? 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adlibXML>
  <recordList>
  <record priref="530000001" creation="2014-06-23T11:36:18" modification="2019-09-13T09:07:12">
  <name>
......

<input.name>ovandhuynslager</input.name>
  <input.time>15:37:34</input.time>
</record>
</recordList>
</adlibXML>

Comment: in browser : This page contains the following errors:

error on line 417133 at column 12: Opening and ending tag mismatch: record line 0 and adlibXML
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: I can't help you with this. I can't possibly debug 417,133 lines of XML for you here in the comments, I hope that seems logical to you. Apart from that, this error has nothing to do with my code, it has occurred in exactly the same way before you tried my changes. Either that, or your XML file has changed in the meantime.

Comment: I understand. Thank you anyhow. This was helpful.

Comment: What was it in the end?

Comment: the file got corrupted somehow along the way. After breaking my head for far too long I made a new export and now it works like a charm. Lessons learned.